# How to use path relative to user home in PropertySource

Tags: java, spring, annotations, applicationcontext

Spring expressions doesn't work inside the PropertySource annotation.

```
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application.properties",
        "#{systemProperties['user.home']}/.app.properties" })
@Configuration
public class Config {
@Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer result = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        result.setOrder(0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can directly use `file:${user.home}` to load a file under user home:

```
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application.properties", 
                  "file:${user.home}/.app.properties" })
@Configuration
public class Config {
}
```